# Lower memory consumption with byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I got alot of byte arrays in my application, which contain often the same value in succession. I need access on this array all the time though, so a compression could lead to problems with performance. My program consumes 1.5GB of memory (Task Manager), of which 1GB is byte arrays only.

Is there a way to handle this type of data better?

To make clear what im talking about: Im working on an voxel engine, and those byte arrays represent the type of voxel (so a "air"-voxel could be contained quite often in succession).

I need to save as much memory as possible.

Comment: so you know which byte array is not necessary ?

Comment: Well those who only contain air are not saved anyways. But the others are filled with noise generated values.

Comment: @user3088126 could you regenerate the noise generated values or avoid generating them unless the data is actually visible to the user.  The only squares you need to record are the ones the user has seen.

Comment: If you are running a server, a few GB isn't much, but if you are running on a PC it can matter,  Have you consider using memory mapped files.  These have the advantage of using very little heap and being saved as you update them. If the pages of the file haven't been used in a while the OS can take them out of memory and add them back in if you use them again.

Comment: I need the data saved (generation will take longer... it's not only noise later on) and I need the data to generate the render data. And what exactly are memory mapped files and are they available in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a use-case for the [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern): create a kind of proxy class instead of accessing the arrays directly. These proxies would access a common store. Every time you add a new array, the proxy would look into the store whether an equal byte array already exists and reference that instead. This eliminates duplicates.

Of course, this pattern requires the array to be immutable. If you need to modify them, you would first need to duplicate the array, then modify it, and again "deduplicate".

Comment: The arrays can be changed anywhen and also can be deleted, or new ones can added at any time... thats the problem... But I think I got an idea now...

Comment: There are multiple ways to implement a flyweight pattern: you don't necessarily need to use a proxy object (although in your case, it could probably help gathering all operations in one place). You could also work with such a store directly. Like: `workingArray = store.deduplicate(workingArray);`. The first time, you'd get the same array back. The second time, you'd get first array again.

Comment: I now solved it by only reuse arrays that really appear always, because trying to cache noise values won't help much. I'm testing performance right now.... EDIT: I now save at least 300MB heap space. Thanks for your hint :)

Comment: forget it... at least 500MB o.o This works extremely good... But later it may only be less of that value but that will still be ok :) Thank your very much!